# Appcelerator: BlackBerry & iOs?

Tags: ios, blackberry, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a requirement to create an app that works on BlackBerry (10%) and iOs (90%).  Appcelerator Titanium looks like it does it, but BlackBerry dev is only supported on Windows and iOs dev is only supported on Mac.  Am I missing something?  How have people overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a restriction of the native SDKs. To create iOS apps you're always required to have a Mac because of Xcode has all the libraries required for compiling iOS apps. Blackberry can be compiled on all platforms but the simulator is only available for Windows. Details available [here](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/bb/). So developing with Titanium for iOS & Blackberry requires at least a Mac with a VM for the BB simulator.

Android for instance has SDKs and its emulator available for all mayor platforms.

Comment: You can also use virtual machines which having Mac. You need to install Xcode in that.

Comment: From my experience the other way around is more powerful. Emulating OS X requires OS X Server and the licenses are not that cheap. Having a Mac is also not cheap but emulating only this emulator is more powerful instead of emulating the whole system.